# PHP cURL not working on some devices (Laptops + Mobiles)

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to autocomplete location using googleapis, but it is working fine ONLY on few devices. Does anyone have a clue

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=".$locality."&key=xxx");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $result = json_decode($output);
```

Comment: maybe the device's location isn't enabled?

Comment: I doubt that you are actually running PHP/cURL _on_ those devices …?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running cURL within the same network, try turning on verbose to find out what were the problem on those devices:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
```

You include mobiles on your title. Do you explicitly mean that you are running PHP on your mobile or you are accessing your webserver that runs cURL? There can be many reasons of why is it not working, please provide more details